# Restler tests with behat

Tags: behat, restler

I did a fresh install of Luracast/Restler using Composer and am unable to get any behat tests to run.  I'm a newbie to both Restler and behat, so I may be making a beginners mistake, but according to the documentation, all I need to do is change the root URL in behat.yml and then type bin/behat.

Here is the error message I'm getting when I type `vendor/bin/behat`.

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  Context class not found.                                                   
  Maybe you have provided a wrong or no `bootstrap` path in your behat.yml:  
  http://docs.behat.org/guides/7.config.html#paths                           



behat [--init] [-f|--format="..."] [--out="..."] [--lang="..."] [--[no-]ansi] [--[no-]time] [--[no-]paths] [--[no-]snippets] [--[no-]snippets-paths] [--[no-]multiline] [--[no-]expand] [--story-syntax] [-d|--definitions="..."] [--name="..."] [--tags="..."] [--cache="..."] [--strict] [--dry-run] [--stop-on-failure] [--rerun="..."] [--append-snippets] [--append-to="..."] [features]


Content-type: text/html
```

Here is my behat.yml file:

```
# behat.yml
default:
    context:
        parameters:
            base_url: http://<MY_DOMAIN>.com/restler3/sampleproject/public
```

I've tried specifying both the paths.features and path.bootstrap variables with both absolute and relative paths with no success.

```
# behat.yml
default:
    paths:
        features: features
        bootstrap:  features/bootstrap
    context:
        parameters:
            base_url: http://<MY_DOMAIN>.com/restler3/sampleproject/public
```

I would really like to use Restler for an API project that I'm starting, but I need to be able to run tests, so any help in getting me over this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up Behat using `behat --init`?

Behat needs features and bootstrap directories in order to run. You can create these by entering `behat --init` on the command line. See the [Behat documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/quick_intro.html#basic-usage) for more information about this:

> Create a new directory and setup behat inside that directory:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir ls_project
> $ cd ls_project
> $ behat --init
> ```
>
> The `behat --init` will create a `features/` directory with some basic things to get your started.

Behat will run a test method for every line in your test file. These methods are contained in *contexts*. To write the sort of feature tests used in the [Restler examples](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/) you'll need to use the "`RestContext`" which is included with Restler. Copy the contents of `vendor/luracast/restler/features/bootstrap` into your Behat bootstrap directory in order to be able to make use of these (you'll need `FeatureContext.php` too: this instantiates the `RestContext`).

Restler's feature tests make use of [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) so you'll also need to add that to your `composer.json`:

```
{
   "require-dev": {
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~3.1.1"
   }
}
```